# Invalid Registration when sending message to mobile device via GCM

Tags: android, servlets, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am implementing Push notification for multiple mobile devices using GCM. When I tried running 2 emulators at a time and sending message through `JSP` page its working fine. After installing my apk file in my mobile device I am getting registration Id but if I am trying to send message through `JSP` to that particular device I am getting error like **Invalid Registration**. I have searched in google but still I didn't get proper solution for my problem

I am using `sender.send(message, regIdList, 1);` this statement in `Servlet` to send message from `JSP` page to android devices.

```
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("My GCM message :X:X")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,noBuilder.build());
```

Please suggest some solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

What's in regIdList?
Invalid Registration from GCM means they don't have the token ID your server is sending. If you are parsing them out of a file, maybe try a trim() on white space?